# How do I loop through all the pixels in an image starting from the bottom?

Tags: java, loops, image-processing, iteration, pixel

I'm trying to create a program that will detect a blue line and black out all of the pixels above it, but not below. See method below:

```
public static void findBlueLine(Picture p) {
Pixel[][] pixels = p.getPixels2D();
    for(int y = 0; y < p.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < p.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (isBlueLine(pixels[y][x])) {
                pixels[y][x].setColor(Color.BLACK);
                //for(int m = y; m < p.getHeight(); m++) {
                    //pixels[m][x].setColor(Color.BLACK);
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of problems? Why did you comment out that innermost loop?

Comment: Looking back I figured out why it doesn't work, I am working on a project that blacks out all pixels above a certain color line(for robot stuff) as well as identify red balls. I had the box set to blue so it would detect that and black out the entire screen. Changed the color of box and it works. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making the assumption that you have one blue line on your screen. This blue line can be at any angle and start and end at any coordinates. I am assuming the line does not exist off of the screen.

This code should work for all lines.

```
public static void findBlueLine(Picture p) {
    Pixel[][] pixels = p.getPixels2D();
    Bool aboveLine = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < p.getWidth(); x++) {
        aboveLine = false;        

        for(int y = p.getHeight-1; 0 <= y ; y--) {
            if(aboveLine == true) {
                pixels[y][x].setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if (isBlueLine(pixels[y][x])) {
                aboveLine = true;
            }  
        }

    }
}
```